# MySQL REGEXP to match the whole word only

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, substring

How can I match the whole word in mysql?

For instance, if I type in '**lau**', I **don't** want to match '**laura**' or '**laurance**'.

Below is my working query that matches '**lau**' with '**laura**'

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT

        p.page_id,
        p.page_url AS url,
        p.page_title AS title,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.page_content_1, ' ', 500) AS content,
        EXTRACT(DAY FROM p.page_backdate) AS date,
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM p.page_backdate) AS month,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM p.page_backdate) AS year

    FROM root_pages AS p

    WHERE p.page_hide != '1'
    AND p.page_url != 'cms'
    AND p.page_url != 'search'

    ORDER BY p.page_created DESC
) x
WHERE x.content REGEXP  '>[^<]*lau'
```

Any idea to fix my `REGEXP`?

The reason I use `REGEXP '>[^<]*searchtext'` is that my contents have html tags, such as,

```
<p class="heading-sitemap">About us</p>
<ul>
<li class="subheading-sitemap">The team</li>
<li><a href="#">Introduction to gt</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Simon x</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Cathrin xe</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Patrick x</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Laurence x</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tessa x</a></li>>
</ul>
```

I don't want to search the word may fall inside the tags such as `<a href="http://laura.com">`.

Comment: Seems you require a lot of work, and a lot of filtering here. good luck. I suggest you do the filtering step by step. This may require sub queries and/or multiple queries.

Comment: See also SO's Related section, in the right side bar. A lot of users have had the same problems before. -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

REGEXP '[^<]*lau[[:>:]]'

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), [[:>:]] will match a word boundary at the end of a word

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down your current regexp:

```
>[^<]*lau

>      match the character '>'
[^<]*  match 0 or more non-'<' characters
lau    match 'lau'
```

So this would match the following:

```
>bbblau
>bbb<lau
>lau
><lau
```

I assume what you want is to match the following:

```
>lau
```

But not:

```
>laubbb
><lau
>bbb<lau
```

In that case, the following regexp would work:

```
>lau( |<|$)
```

Edit: using the method shown by andrewsi might be cleaner:

```
>lau[[:>:]]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it returns some strange result though. only this work ok `'>[^<]*lau[[:>:]]'` though.

Answer (score 2):

andrewsi code didn't work for me, but this REGEXP solved my problem.

`m_city` REGEXP '[[:<:]]YOUR_CITY[[:>:]]'