# Search query optimization in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a search query.
I have a string "thomas alva edison" in my table.
I want to display this string if the user searches for,

> thomas alva edison,thomas,alva,edison,thomas alva,thomas edison,etc

but not for

> tho,son,alv,etc

what I did is

```
select name from tbl_names where name like "."'%".$key."%'
```

How can I modify this query to get the correct results.

Comment: Look up *Fulltext search* in MySQL

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would I implement a simple site search with php and mySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386914/how-would-i-implement-a-simple-site-search-with-php-and-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommended to use REGEXP for word search in query,

A query should be like:

```
SELECT name FROM `tbl_names` WHERE `name` REGEXP '[[:<:]]thomas[[:>:]]'
```

Hope this will be useful to you.  For more details please check this [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125464/mysql-regexp-to-match-the-whole-word-only).

Comment: thanks this works fine. Is there any way to return "Thomas alva edison" when searching like "thomas christopher,chris thomas,david thomas"

Comment: No, Regular Expression is use for special case when we want exact ouput, It's not works as 'Like' to fetch relative rows!! I suggest you to use 'LIKE', if you want suggestion as you required!

Answer (score 3):

MySQL provides a wonderful way (Full-text Search) of implementing a little search.
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/full-text-search-using-mysql-full-text-search-capabilities/

example :

```
select name from tbl_names WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST ('thomas');
```

We have many options in full text search and less then MySQL 5.6 MYISAM engine only.

Comment: As of MySQL 5.6, FULL TEXT search is available in InnoDB also.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this:

```
$sql = "select name from tbl_names where ";
$array = explode(" ",$key);
$or = "";
foreach($array as $word) {
  if(strlen(trim($word))>0) {
    $sql.= $or."(name like '%".$word."%')";
    $or = " OR ";
  }
}
```